# Cumulative Matching Characteristic (CMC) curve for multiclass setting

Tags: model-evaluation, multi-class

The CMC curve is supposed to be calculated for a gallery and a probe set, both sets of vectors identifying some person. What if I train a model on a closed set of say 10 people with 10 samples (e.g. images of their face) per person. Then how would does one generally define the gallery versus the probe set? Does the gallery need to consist of *different* people per se?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question. Yes, the gallery consists of samples of different persons. It's a subset of the target set. The probes are part of the query set and they are matched with the gallery. The choice of the gallery influences evaluation.

More details are given in [The FERET Evaluation Methodology for Face-Recognition Algorithms](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/IR/nistir6264.pdf) which is also discussed in Jain's handbook for face recognition.

However, in this methodology class-insensitive algorithms are used (for Fisher Discriminant Analysis a class-insensitive variant is referred to). So every image in the 'known' target set is considered a different person even when it's an image of the same person in different lighting. The goal was to find vector embeddings, representations for faces. On the basis of these embeddings a similarity can be calculated and the CMC curve can be obtained by determining the rank of each gallery image when its similarity is calculated with respect to some probe image.

[image: FERET methodology]

For multi-gallery-shot settings there are variants which are [discussed here](https://cysu.github.io/open-reid/notes/evaluation_metrics.html). Quote :

- [CUHK03](https://cysu.github.io/open-reid/notes/www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2014/papers/Li_DeepReID_Deep_Filter_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf): Query and gallery sets are from different camera views. For each query, they randomly sample one instance for each gallery identity, and compute a CMC curve in the single-gallery-shot setting. The random sampling is repeated for N times and the expected CMC curve is reported.
- [Market-1501](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2015/papers/Zheng_Scalable_Person_Re-Identification_ICCV_2015_paper.pdf): Query and gallery sets could have same camera views, but for each individual query identity, his/her gallery samples from the same camera are excluded. They do not randomly sample only one instance for each gallery identity. This means the query will always match the “easiest” positive sample in the gallery while does not care other harder positive samples when computing CMC.